# Having a different result when finding the order of the permutation in a different way!

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have an exam next week so I'm preparing myself.

In my book, there's this question:

Suppose that $α$ is a $2-cycle$ and $β$ is a $t-cycle$, then prove that $αβα$ is a $t-cycle$.

The solution is really convincing, but I tried to solve it in an alternative way and got a different result!

**My way:**

$β$ is a $t-cycle$, then it can be written as a product of $t-1$ transpositions, and then $αβα$ can be written as a product of $1+t-1+1 = t+1 $ transpositions ( as $α$ is itself a transposition ). Therefore $αβα$ is a $t+2- cycle $.

Surely, I have a mistake somewhere, and maybe in all my way. What is it?

Comment: Just because something can be written as n transpositions doesn't mean it's the shortest form! Consider $n=2$, and alpha = beta = swap the two elements.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl: Im really sorry but can't get it. Can you repeat with more details?

Comment: Let alpha = (1,2), beta = (1,2). So alpha and beta are 2 cycles, no? But what is alpha beta alpha = (1,2)(1,2)(1,2)?

Comment: Alpha beta alpha is equal to (1,2) here, so it's a product pf 3 transpositions but its length is not 4. Is there any rule to keep in mind here?

Comment: @ArtimisFowl: So can I conclude that if alpha is a t-cycle then it can be written as a product of t-1 transpositions but the reverse is not true?

Comment: Exactly, the reverse version that would work is something like if the product of  (t-1) transpositions can't be simplified and are in "order" (ie, (1,3)(3,4)(4,2) etc), then their product is a t cycle. In general this is hard to guarantee methinks.

Comment: There is this useful and more general fact: if $\beta = (i_1,...,i_t)\in S_n$ and $\alpha \in S_n$, then $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(i_1),...,\alpha(i_t))$.